# How can I shift all window numbers down by the appropriate number to “collapse” the window numbers?

Tags: command-line, tmux, command-line-tool

I am (manually) moving this question to `SO` from `superuser` because I observed there is a `tmux` tag here, and I believe it is a sufficiently unusual question that the power users of `tmux` on `SO` might better be able to address it.

Suppose I have `5` windows, and I decide to delete window `1`.

Is it possible to shift all the window numbers down by `1` with a single command, so that `2` becomes `1`, `3` becomes `2`, `4` becomes `3`, and `0` stays where it is?

The above is merely an example. I am wondering if it can be done for an arbitrary number of windows, and an arbitrary number of "missing" windows.

I have looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/343572/how-do-i-reorder-tmux-windows) and it certainly makes things easier, but it does not address the current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in *tmux* 1.7, the `move-window` command knows the `-r` option that tells it to renumber windows in the desired manner. For example—after closing your window at index 1—you could run `tmux move-window -r` (from a shell) or type *Prefix* + `:move-window -r` (in an attached client).

If you always want windows to be automatically renamed, then you can set the `renumber-windows` session option. If you want this for all your sessions, then you might want to set it globally in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g renumber-windows on
```

Answer (score 0):

User [gospes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250406/gospes) provided [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136902) that I believe does exactly what you want. It seems to work perfectly on my end and it's a simple addition to `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind R                                      \
    set -g renumber-windows on\;            \
    new-window\; kill-window\;              \
    set -g renumber-windows off\;           \
    display-message "Windows reordered..."
```

The command `set -g renumber-windows on` by itself works fine, of course, but can be a little jarring if you're not ready for an immediate renumbering.